# .get method not returning value even though I copy/pasted the key into it

Tags: apex, map, debugging, system, get

I'm creating a map based on a custom object in my org. Basically this is the code for it.

```
Map<String, String> translationMap = new Map<String, String>();
List<StageNameTranslation__c> myTranslations = [Select RecordTypeName__c, LS_StageName__c, SF_StageName__c from StageNameTranslation__c];
        for(StageNameTranslation__c t: myTranslations) {
            translationMap.put(t.RecordTypeName__c + '-' + t.LS_StageName__c, t.SF_StageName__c);
        }
```

Then I use the .get method to get the value for a specific key. In this scenario I have hard-coded the key as a string for testing. the "combined" variable.

```
String combined = 'Detox Admission-Admitted to Facility';
String mappedStageName = translationMap.get(combined); // equal to translationMap.get('Detox Admission-Admitted to Facility')
System.debug('mappedStageName: ' + mappedStageName); // expect to get the value .. in this case 'Admitted To Facility'
```

Since I am facing this issue, I print out every key/value in the map

```
for(String key : translationMap.keyset()){
     system.debug('The Current Key ='+ key);
     system.debug('The Current value ='+ translationMap.get(key));
}
```

the system.debug for the String variable mappedStageName is null
However when I look at the debugs, I copy and paste the key(the 'combined' variable), and it is a match for the key in the map.
[image]

I would expect to get the value from this since the keys are a match.
so why is it null?

[image]

I even copy and pasted the key from the debug and did:

```
System.debug(translationMap.get('Detox Admission-Admitted to Facility'));
```

and that returned null as well.

Comment: note also that map keys are case-sensitive

Comment: ^^^ is the answer.

Comment: thanks, i just noticed the capitol 'T' ... sigh

Comment: @cropredy You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map keys are case sensitive (unlike Apex variable names, Sobject field names, etc)

In your debug log, you have

```
Detox Admission-Admitted To Facility
```

But in the copy-paste to `System.debug` you used

```
Detox Admission-Admitted to Facility
```

`...To...` versus `...to...`